# Second derivative as a multilinear map

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multilinear-algebra

Well, let's assume that $T=(f\circ g)$. 
How do I compute $D^2 T(y)(v,w)$?

I tried $D^2 T(y)(v,w)=(D_wD_vT)(y)$, i.e. do first the directional derivatives and then compute them at $y$.

$D_vT=((Df)\circ g) \circ (Dg )\ (v)$, then I try to apply again the chain rule to $D_wD_vT$.

My best (incorrect) effort gives $((D((Df)\circ g))\circ Dg \ (v))\circ D^2g(v,w)=((D^2f)\circ g)\circ Dg )\circ Dg \ (v))\circ D^2g(v,w)$ which is a big mess and this doesn't look like what I'm supposed to get, which is $$D^2f(x)(Dg(y)v,Dg(y)w)+Df(x)D^2g(y)(v,w)$$

How would one proceed? any help would be appreciated.

P.S: If you're downvoting this question, at least tell me what's wrong it with  so that I can improve it. Thanks.

Comment: Care to share that big mess? It is indeed a little bit longer...

Comment: @user251257 I wrote  a big mess as in what I get is definitely incorrect, and I have no idea how to do it correctly... =D I'll add some of what I've tried.

Comment: Just apply the product rule to $D_v T$. Be careful about the order of the arguments.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ were scalar valued, wouldn't you expect somewhere a $+$ in the second derivative...?

Comment: @user251257 That's the thing. In that way we're thinking about matrices representing the functions, and not the functions themselves. I was trying to learn how to do that without thinking about the product rule.

Comment: Composition of linear maps is a product ... Now, for linear map valued functions $A,B$ and a vector $v$ we have $D_w (A(x) B(x) v) = D A(x)[w] B(x)v + A(x) DB(x)[w] v $.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks for your comment. Wouldn't it be possible to apply a 2nd time the chain rule?

By the way, were you the one to downvote this question?

Comment: @user251257 could you write an answer to this question? Also, how do you make your comment compatible with the new info I added in the question?

Comment: I haven't down voted. I will post an answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that for a **continuous** bilinear map $\mathcal B : X\times Y \to Z$ on normed spaces $X,Y,Z$ we have
$$ D\mathcal B(x, y)[h, k] = \mathcal B(h, y) + \mathcal B(x, k). $$
This can be directly shown using the definition of frechet differentiability.

Now, the space of continuous linear maps is again a normed space and the composition / multiplication of compatible continuous linear maps is bilinear and continuous. For $A(y) = Df(g(y))$ and $B(y) = Dg(y)$ we have
\begin{align*} 
D^2 T(y)[w] &= D( A(y) \, B(y) )[w] \\
&= DA(y)[w] \, B(y) + A(y) \, DB(y)[w] \\
&= D^2 f(g(y))[Dg(y)[w],\, Dg(y) \,\cdot\,] + Df(g(y)) \, D^2g(y)[w,\,\cdot\,].
\end{align*}

Notice that the **frechet** differential of order $2$ is a symmetric bilinear map. Thus, the order of the linear arguments of $D^2 f$ and $D^2 g$ is arbitrary.

*Additional Notes:*

Say, we have $f: Z \to E$, $g: Y \to Z$ and $T = f\circ g: Y \to E$.

1. $D^2 f$ is recursively defined as $D(Df)$. Here, $Df$ maps into $L(Z; E)$, space of continuous linear map from $Z$ into $E$. So, $D^2 f$ maps into $L(Z; L(Z;E))$ (isomorph to continuous bilinear maps $L(Z, Z; E)$). Now, with mild assumptions on $E$, $D^2 f(z)$ is in fact symmetric, that is
   $$ (D^2 f(z)v)w = (D^2 f(z)w)v =: D^2 f(z)[v, w] $$
   holds for every $v,w\in Z$.
2. Now, consider $A = Df\circ g: Y\to L(Z;E)$ and $B = Dg: Y\to L(Y;Z)$. By chain rule we have
   $$ DA(y)v = D^2 f(g(y))Dg(y)v \in L(Y;E) $$ 
   and
   $$ ((DA(y)v) \, B(y)) \,w = ((D^2 f(g(y))Dg(y)v) \, B(y)) \, w = D^2 f(g(y))[Dg(y) v, B(y) w]. $$
   That doesn't rely on the symmetry of $(v,w)\mapsto (DA(y)v)w$. One just need to track the order of the arguments more carefully.

Comment: Many thanks user. I appreciate your answer a lot. Now, just one more question. In your derivation, in the 2nd equality, are you simply using the derivative of a multilinear function, or something else? because it seems to be more that what you stated before...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: derivative of multilinear function and chain rule.

Comment: got it. Thanks for the effort. ;)

Comment: user, may I interest you in this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026983/product-rule-of-multilinear-mappings-for-directional-derivatives

Comment: user, sorry to come back to this question, but it's related to other one. 

Could you give a bit more details how do you go from lhs to rhs in the last equality? Specifically the part $DA(y)[w]B(y)$ that goes to $D^2f(g(y))(Dg(y)w,Dg(y) \ )$

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Do you understand the equation after $D(AB)$?

Comment: yes, I think so.

Comment: So you stuck at $D^2 T = D(DT) = D(AB)$? But, $A,B$ are defined such that $AB=DT$.

Comment: I'm just stuck at last equality. How from $DA(y)[w]B(y)=D^2f(g(y))[w]\circ Dg(y)$ you get $D^2f(g(y))(Dg(y)w,Dg(y) \ )$

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I have added some notes to the answer. May be it helps.

Comment: It helps a lot! Many thanks ;)